# UDID apps not generating the same UDID on the same device

Tags: ios, ios-provisioning, udid

I've downloaded multiple UDID mobile applications and they are not consistent with the UDID on my iTunes dashboard. UDID+, UDID, and UDID Tool are generating different codes that are no where close...same device. I am just curious as to why.

Comment: `UDID` has been forbidden to use/request/access for developers for few years by now.

Answer (score 2):

Apple doesn't allow to get UDID anymore from iOS6. It's for security reasons. Apple doesn't want you can identify a device. It's the reason because when you try to get an UDID using apps you get something like FFFFFF... If you need to get the UDID of your device you only need to switch your device to your laptop, open iTunes, go to Device and in the Summary option (tab or lateral menu depending of your iTunes version) you will see Serial Number. Click over your serial number with your mouse and you will see the UDID.

- Connect your device to your computer
- Open iTunes
- Click in your device
- Go to Summary option
- Click with your mouse in Serial Number
- Second mouse button click over UDID number to copy it or Cmd + C

Comment: Are you sure apple doesn't allow to get UDID on all models from iOS6?

Comment: @ArnoldBrown Yes I'm sure. Actually this is quite old topic. Anyway you can find some information about it here https://nshipster.com/uuid-udid-unique-identifier/ Today you can find a lot of alternatives using third party libraries or manage it yourself using Keychain for instance to store it.

Answer (score 0):

UDID app store apps doesnt work anymore since apple disapproved using it. If you want to get UDID of yourself or remote devices you can use this [website](http://get.udid.io/) it's super easy and comfortable.